# Adding the clicked li as request parameter

Tags: html, jsp, parameters, request

I try to make a link from a form, I have following code:

```
<form action="details" method="get" id="breadcrumb">
                <button type="submit" id="back" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                    <span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span> Back
                </button>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                  <li onClick="breadcrumb.submit();" id="file">File</li>
                  <li onClick="breadcrumb.submit();" id="format">Format</li>
                  <li onClick="breadcrumb.submit();" id="batch">Batch</li>
                  <li id="payment" class="active">Payment</li>
                </ol>
            </form>
```

I want to add the id from the clicked li as parameter, so I can pass it to my DetailsControllerServlet.

How do I do that?

Comment: Where you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as

```
<li onclick="breadcrumb.submit(this);" id="file">File</li>
```